# Assigning events using Jquery not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have jquery-1.8.3.js referenced.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function Assign()
{
    $(".evo").click(function ()
    {
    showit(this, 'dvEvent');
    });
}
$(document).ready(Assign);
function showit(caller, dv)
{
alert('has been called');
}
</script>
```

On a asp.net page I have a Gridview inside an UpdatePanel. Each row in the GridView has a hyperlink in it (with NavigateUrl="#") with a CssClass of 'evo'.

When I run the page using Internet Explorer and click on any of the hyperlinks in the table (generated by the gridView) that have a class of 'evo' - the function showit() is called and the alert shows.

But in Firefox when I click the links nothing happens.

What do I need to do to get this working in Firefox? Thanks for any help.

Comment: works fine in Firefox http://jsfiddle.net/e2ops84y/

Comment: do the elements exist at time code is run?

Answer (score 0):

I would try the following changes to the javascript code to see if it works,

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
function Assign()
{

    //changed code to select document first and then
    //the .evo class since the document will always exist
    //on a page. This is done just in case the .evo class
    //element was added dynamically
    $(document).on("click",".evo",function ()
    {
    showit(this, 'dvEvent');
    });
}
$(document).ready(Assign);
function showit(caller, dv)
{
alert('has been called');
}
</script>
```